# Sequence: $a_n= \sqrt[3]{x^3+c} - x$ where $c$ is constant and $x$ is a natural number.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Sequence: $a_n= \sqrt[3]{x^3+c} - x$ where $c$ is constant and $x$ is a natural number.
>
> Prove that  $0 < a_n =(n^3+c)^{1/3}-n < \frac{c}{3}n^2$.

I tried to solve the problem, but I can't prove it. Can someone help me please?

Comment: how is $a_n$ defined? in the title there is no $n$...

Comment: sorry my mistake is an=(n^3+c)^(1/3)-n where c is a constant. I have tried to use the squeeze theorem to solve it but it doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not even about sequences ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume, $c\geq 0$:

$$(n^3+c)^{1/3}-n < \frac{c}{3}n^2 \iff (n^3+c)^{1/3} < \frac{c}{3}n^2 + n \iff n^3+c < (\frac{c}{3}n^2 + n)^3 \iff$$

$$n^3+c < d^3n^6 + 3d^2n^5 + 3dn^4 + n^3 \iff c < n^4(d^3n^2+3d^2n +3d)$$

where $d=\frac{c}{3}$. For $n\geq1$ the last disequality is true ($c < n^4 c = 3n^4d$).

Comment: thanks for the help. but thats enough to prove it? i am not understanding very well.

Comment: @AnaBranco check my new edit